Newrelic .NET Core Azure Web App - Cannot get Nuget installed agent working
Hope you dont mind me jumping in here, I have a very similar issue/setup as you.
I'm facing an issue with monitoring my .Net Core 8 application, which is running in a Docker container on a Linux Azure Web App. Despite setting up New Relic, I'm not seeing any data on the New Relic APM & Services dashboard after interacting with the deployed app.
Do I need to add the app to the dashbord or set something up in my account?
or is something not working?
Here's a breakdown of my setup:
Using ASP.NET base image for the runtime environment
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
EXPOSE 4022
Dockerfile Configuration:
Building the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco.csproj", "AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco/"]
COPY ["../AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco.Models/AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco.Models.csproj", "AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco.Models/"]
RUN dotnet restore "AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco/AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco"
RUN dotnet build "AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/build
Publishing the application
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco.csproj" -c Debug -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false
Final runtime image
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENV CORECLR_ENABLE_PROFILING="1"
CORECLR_PROFILER="{36032161-FFC0-4B61-B559-F6C5D41BAE5A}"
CORECLR_PROFILER_PATH="/home/site/wwwroot/newrelic/libNewRelicProfiler.so"
NEW_RELIC_LICENSE_KEY="MY_KEY_IS_HERE"
NEW_RELIC_APP_NAME="My APP NAME IS HERE"
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "AsoRockFood.com.Umbraco.dll"]
Problem:
After deployment, navigating to the website and interacting with it shows no data in New Relic’s APM & Services.
Steps Taken:
I confirmed that Azure’s Application Insights is disabled to avoid conflicts.
The newrelic nuget package 10.23.0 is installed
New Relic environment variables are correctly set in the Dockerfile.
Does anyone have insights on what might be going wrong or what I should check next? Any advice or troubleshooting tips would be greatly appreciated!
